# how extract images from excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file.i tried to extract images from excel using html but images were extracted twice.i want to extract images and save images with corresponding names.

Here is my excel file screenshort.[image]

Can anyone please give me an idea.How to extract images from excel file using (vba or any methods)

Comment: Please share you code you tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will do it (tested on Excel 2010).

```
Sub extractImgs()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim tempChart As String, wsName As String
wsName = ActiveSheet.Name
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.Name Like "Picture*" Then
        shp.Select
        Charts.Add
        ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, wsName
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Height = shp.Height
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width = shp.Width
        tempChart = Mid(ActiveChart.Name, Len(wsName) + 2, 100)
        shp.Copy
        ActiveChart.Paste
        ActiveChart.Export Filename:="C:\images\" & shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ".jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(tempChart).Delete
    End If
 Next 
End Sub
```

In case you need initial VBA intro: from the worksheet with the images, right click on the sheet tab and then "view code", then paste the code there.
Make sure to create a folder named "images" under C:\ before running the code (run it by hitting F5 when cursor is inside the code).

Comment: code is working but if there is two images in a cell how to combine two images with single id

Comment: clarify "combine images". you mean merge two images to one?

Comment: can we do image extraction in ppt also same as excel

Comment: Check this thread for both questions http://www.msofficeforums.com/powerpoint/11546-vba-code-group-picture-export-one.html. LMK if it works for you

Comment: useful code to extract images from excel. But instead of using **_If shp.Name Like "Picture*" Then_**  try and replace the line with **If shp.Type = msoPicture Then**.  Becuase this code was missing some images while downloading.