# How to convert a vba Picture object to an encoded base64 data string?

Tags: excel, vba, base64

I am trying to generate the base64 codification of an image (format `BASE64;JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAA...`) from a picture inserted on an Excel sheet and found as a Picture object.

So far, I have something along the lines:

```
Dim img as Picture
Set img = getPictureInRange("B5")
```

And I would need something that do

```
Debug.Print base64decode(img)
```

I've tried with every option I've found related to VBA, but to no avail.

May I have some help on this matter? or some recommendation?

Thanks

Comment: Give [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638989/4717755) a try

Comment: Thanks PeterT, however that answer provides help for when picture is loaded from a file read, not from a Picture Object, and I didnt manage to adapt it to my case

Answer (score 0):

Based on the work of others, I've been able to do what you want to do, but, with a detour. Basically, the script below first exports an image to a file and then reads the file's contents and converts the contents to b64. The only thing you'd need to change to have this script suit your needs is to delete the exported image files.

```
Rem Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223247/how-extract-images-from-excel-sheets
Sub extractImgs()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim tempChart As String, wsName As String, fileName As String, b64encoded As String

wsName = ActiveSheet.Name
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
        shp.Select
        Charts.Add
        ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, wsName
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Height = shp.Height
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width = shp.Width
        tempChart = Mid(ActiveChart.Name, Len(wsName) + 2, 100)
        shp.Copy
        ActiveChart.Paste
        Rem Change the directory to store your images
        fileName = "E:\Temporary\images\Product-C" & shp.TopLeftCell.Column & "-R" & shp.TopLeftCell.Row & ".JPG"
        ActiveChart.Export fileName:=fileName, FilterName:="jpg"
        ActiveSheet.Shapes(tempChart).Delete
        Debug.Print shp.Name & ": " & shp.TopLeftCell.Column & "/" & shp.TopLeftCell.Row & "(" & shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ")"
        Rem Get the file's contents and encode them
        b64encoded = EncodeFile(fileName)
        Cells(shp.TopLeftCell.Row, shp.TopLeftCell.Column + 2) = b64encoded
    End If
 Next
End Sub

Rem Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043393/convert-image-jpg-to-base64-in-excel-vba
Public Function EncodeFile(strPicPath As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded
    Dim objXML, objDocElem, objStream

    ' Open data stream from picture
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile (strPicPath)
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()
    EncodeFile = objDocElem.Text

    ' Clean all
    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set objDocElem = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer above works, there are some caveats I encountered while trying to generate product data which could be imported into Odoo. The first was not immediately obvious but Odoo started complaining that the base64 data was invalid. After some troubleshooting, I found that this was due to a limitation in Excel which restricts the size of a cell's content to 32KB of data. So, since a number of my images were exceeding this, the validate phase of the import failed accordingly. In order to work around this, I chose to generate a CSV file directly from within VBA.

Secondly, the MSXML library adds line feeds every 72 characters. Although as per specification, a base 64 decode should ignore characters like this, the CSV format certainly was not compatible. So, the script was modified to remove all line feeds as well.

The updated script which generates a file which can be directly imported into Odoo, is listed below:

```
Sub extractImgs()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim tempChart As String, wsName As String
    Dim csvFileName As String, imageFileName As String, b64encoded As String, line As String
    Dim header(0 To 19) As Variant, fields(0 To 19) As Variant
    
    header(0) = "Active"
    header(1) = "Barcode"
    header(2) = "Can be Sold"
    header(3) = "Can be Purchased"
    header(4) = "Cost"
    header(5) = "Favorite"
    header(6) = "Internal Reference"
    header(7) = "Name"
    header(8) = "Quantity On Hand"
    header(9) = "Image"
    header(10) = "Description"
    header(11) = "Point of Sale Category"
    header(12) = "Product Category"
    header(13) = "Product Tags"
    header(14) = "Product Type"
    header(15) = "Responsible"
    header(16) = "Sales Price"
    header(17) = "Type"
    header(18) = "Unit of Measure"
    header(19) = "Purchase UoM"
    
    fields(0) = "TRUE" 'Active
    fields(1) = "" 'Barcode
    fields(2) = "FALSE" 'Can be Sold'
    fields(3) = "TRUE" 'Can be Purchased
    fields(4) = "1,000.00" 'Cost
    fields(5) = "Normal" 'Favorite
    fields(6) = "" 'Internal Reference
    ' 7 = Name = "Name"
    ' 8 = QuantityOnHand = "Quantity On Hand"
    ' 9 = Image = "Image"
    ' 10 = Description = "Description"
    fields(11) = "" 'Point of Sale Category
    fields(12) = "All / Buyable / Packaging" 'Product Category
    fields(13) = "" 'Product Tags
    fields(14) = "Storable Product" 'Product Type
    fields(15) = "Purchasing" 'Responsible
    fields(16) = "1.00" 'Sales Price
    fields(17) = "Storable Product" 'Type
    fields(18) = "Units" 'Unit of Measure
    fields(19) = "Units" 'Purchase UoM
   
    wsName = ActiveSheet.Name
    csvFileName = "E:\Temporary\exported-products.csv"
    Open csvFileName For Output As #1
    Call WriteLine(header)
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
            shp.Select
            Charts.Add
            ActiveChart.Location xlLocationAsObject, wsName
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Height = shp.Height
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Width = shp.Width
            tempChart = Mid(ActiveChart.Name, Len(wsName) + 2, 100)
            shp.Copy
            ActiveChart.Paste
            imageFileName = "E:\Temporary\images\Product-C" & shp.TopLeftCell.Column & "-R" & shp.TopLeftCell.Row & ".JPG"
            ActiveChart.Export fileName:=imageFileName, FilterName:="jpg"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(tempChart).Delete
            Debug.Print shp.Name & ": " & shp.TopLeftCell.Column & "/" & shp.TopLeftCell.Row & "(" & shp.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 1).Value & ")"
            b64encoded = EncodeFile(imageFileName)
            ' Excel is limited to 32KB per cell so, outputting data as CSV instead.
            ' Cells(shp.TopLeftCell.Row, shp.TopLeftCell.Column + 2) = b64encoded
            
            fields(7) = Cells(shp.TopLeftCell.Row, shp.TopLeftCell.Column - 3)
            fields(8) = Cells(shp.TopLeftCell.Row, shp.TopLeftCell.Column - 2)
            fields(9) = b64encoded
            fields(10) = Cells(shp.TopLeftCell.Row, shp.TopLeftCell.Column - 1)
            
            Call WriteLine(fields)
        End If
    Next
    
    Close #1
End Sub


Public Function EncodeFile(strPicPath As String) As String
    Const adTypeBinary = 1          ' Binary file is encoded
    Dim objXML, objDocElem, objStream

    ' Open data stream from picture
    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile (strPicPath)
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXml2.DOMDocument")
    Set objDocElem = objXML.createElement("Base64Data")
    objDocElem.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objDocElem.nodeTypedValue = objStream.Read()
    ' Removing newline even though it is allowed
    ' CSV format still requires this.
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837881/base64-encode-with-stream-stringtobinary-inserts-a-newline-breaking-the-string
    ' b64EncodedData = Replace(objDocElem.Text, vbLf, "")
    EncodeFile = Replace(objDocElem.Text, vbLf, "")

    ' Clean all
    Set objXML = Nothing
    Set objDocElem = Nothing
    Set objStream = Nothing

End Function


Public Sub WriteLine(ByRef myData As Variant)
    Dim line
    
    line = ""
    For Index = LBound(myData) To UBound(myData) - 1
        line = line + Chr(34) & myData(Index) & Chr(34) & ","
    Next
    
    line = line + Chr(34) & myData(UBound(myData)) & Chr(34)
    Print #1, line
End Sub
```